# Record video with timestamp on vlc

Tags: vlc-media-player

I want to record from my webcam with vlc and show / save the current time within the videodata. It is not about the filename, the time should be shown inside the frames (as subtitle would be cool, so I can turn it on / off). There are some questions about it on google, but without satisfying answers.

I would prefer recording via command line.

Hope anyone can help!

Greetz paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a marquee filter to stream the current time within the video data

```
marq{marquee='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S',position=6}
```

This is the full command to stream from your webcam with the current time

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev=%cam1% :dshow-adev=%mic1% --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,sfilter=marq{marquee='%%Y-%%m-%%d_%%H:%%M:%%S',position=6}}:file{dst=%file1%,no-overwrite}"
```

- As I use it in an Windows batch file I need to escape the % with another %
- You have to set %cam1%, %mic1% and %file1% (See how to get them via gui: [#1126778](https://superuser.com/questions/1126778/get-command-line-string-for-gui-configured-vlc-setting))
- Adding a space to the marquee text leads to an error