# Get command line string for GUI configured VLC setting

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player

I am trying to stream / record a video from my webcam. I get it to work by configuring everything via the VLC GUI (e.g. [How to record your webcam with VLC](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-your-webcam-with-vlc/)).

I have to do this multiple time, so I wonder, if I can "export" the configuration to run it from the command line.

I didn't find anything appropriate in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find a solution to "export" the full configuration. But I found the necessary parts, which have to be put together for my use case (recording from webcam).

1) The [input query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7Bn1.png)

2) The [output query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRuGx.png)

Which lead to a complete command line string like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" dshow:// :dshow-vdev=Integrated Camera :dshow-adev=Mikrofon (2- High Definition Au :live-caching=300 --sout "#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\test.mp4}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I only tried the output part for a different conversion task, but I found one can find the options by opening the "Messages" window (Ctrl+M) and increasing the verbosity to 2.